# Unity error shows-no android device connected

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I created a game in unity that I want to download on my phone. I plug in my Samsung galaxy s7 edge and click on build and run.

[image: Build and Run]

It starts building as usual, but then the error shows:

[image]

I don't know why this is happening. I have enabled USB debugging on my phone and did all the requirements-(click build number seven times, enable USB debugging)
I also disabled and re-enabled the USB debugging but it didn't work. I even downloaded the SDK and JDK!

Comment: Try disabling USB debugging and re-enabling.  If you didn't also see an 'accept key' dialog on the Samsung, setup might not be complete.  This very thing got me yesterday.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that. However, the same problem shows.

Comment: also ensure that android studio is not running because it will disable adb for unity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few solutions to this problem. 
Someone already mentioned try plug/unplug. Sometimes you have to change option from charging to transfer files or other. 
Another solution that will probably work is killing adb server. Launch your OS console and type:

```
adb kill-server
```

then restart it by

```
adb start-server
```

This will force pc-phone communication to be restarted, and probably will solve your problem. Make sure the Android SDK path is correct in your Unity settings too.

Comment: How do I navigate to the windows OS console?

Comment: press windows+R (will launch windows run program) type cmd and press Enter

Comment: When I do this I get this error: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You should have it installed on your pc, path might not be set, follow instructions here: https://www.howtodroid.com/2014/02/how-to-add-adb-command-prompt-windows.html